# Deploy Play 2.0.2 to Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework

I tried to push my application to Heroku. I followed the instructions at https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ProductionHeroku.

When I run `git push heroku master`, it fails with the following message:

> [error] {file:/tmp/build_21x20nx2i16sz/}projecttrunk/compile:sources: scala.tools.nsc.interactive.FreshRunReq
>   [error] Total time: 48 s, completed Jul 9, 2012 6:46:55 PM

I don't know where the issue is, as the app is running fine on my machine.

My `Procfile`:

> web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL} -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE 1:

I just pushed again and now no compile error comes up? I don't understand...
Now the application is crashing with the following message:

> 2012-07-09T19:02:55+00:00 app[web.1]: This application is already running (Or delete the RUNNING_PID file).

UPDATE 2:

I removed the RUNNING_PID file and now the following errors are showing up from `heroku logs`:

> 2012-07-09T19:33:36+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
>   2012-07-09T19:34:02+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET radiant-sword-2133.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2012-07-09T19:38:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>   2012-07-09T19:38:03+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL} -Ddb.default.drive
>   r=org.postgresql.Driver`
>   2012-07-09T19:38:04+00:00 app[web.1]: This application is already running (Or delete the RUNNING_PID file).
>   2012-07-09T19:38:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 255
>   2012-07-09T19:38:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   2012-07-09T19:44:32+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 0
>   2012-07-09T19:44:32+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
>   2012-07-09T19:45:07+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET radiant-sword-2133.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to connect to heroku using:

```
heroku run bash
```

Then, try to delete the file:

```
rm RUNNING_PID
```

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssh-access

**EDIT** from James comment

The RUNNING_PID must be removed from your git repository.

Comment: I did - now I am getting the error msg: 2012-07-09T19:31:29+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET xxx-xxx-xxx.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: this was already a log message. I posted some logs after Update 2.

Comment: Very strange... If you can, try to re-create a new app on heroku and deploy to it (it may be a corrupted jar or something...)

Comment: Deleting the `RUNNING_PID` via `heroku run bash` won't delete it from the slug file.  You need to make sure that file isn't in your git repo.  Remove it from the git repo and re-push to Heroku.

Comment: @JamesWard - I added a new app to heroku and removed RUNNING_PID file. That did the trick! Thanks a lot for your help